# Cannot figure out why part of my copy commands are working and some are not

Tags: powershell, copy

Code is at the bottom. Simply put, when I run the code, my .ps1 files get moved no problem, but for some reason any file with "Lec" as a part of its name will pop up this error message:

> cp : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Win213x_Lec_filename.docx' because it does not 
>       exist.

I do not understand why this is happening when it recognizes the file name, and I double checked the exact file is in the directory with the exact name, but my ps1 files have no issue.

```
$sub1 = "Lectures"
$sub2 = "Labs"
$sub3 = "Assignment"
$sub4 = "Scripts"
$DirectoryName = "test"
$Win213CopyFiles = ls C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Win213Copy
$count = 0
foreach ($i in $Win213CopyFiles)
{
    if ($i -match ".*Lec.*")
    {
        cp $i C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test\Lectures
        $count = $count + 1
    }
    elseif ($i -match ".*Lab.*")
    {
        cp $i C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\$DirectoryName\$sub2
        $count = $count + 1
    }
    elseif ($i -match ".*Assign.*")
    {
        cp $i C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\$DirectoryName\$sub3
        $count = $count + 1
    }
    elseif ($i -match ".*.ps1")
    {
        cp $i C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\$DirectoryName\$sub4
        $count = $count + 1
    }

Write-host "$i"
}

## Step 9: Display a message "<$count> files moved"
###################################

Write-host "$count files moved"
```

Comment: There seems to be a discrepancy between the path in your error message (`C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\`) and and the path that you're searching (`C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Win213Copy`). Can you explain that?

Comment: Suggestion: Step through your code in the ISE and debug the lines that are not working.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am pulling the files from the Win213Copy directory in a variable Win213CopyFiles. My for each block is going through each file and supposed to send it to a certain directory depending on the naming scheme of it. It is supposed to then copy the file to the assigned directory, which is what the line "cp $i C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test\Lectures" is supposed to do. It's also an absolute path so there's no reason that I can see for why it cannot find the file when it's in that path. And also for why the ps1 files had no problem. Let me know if that answered your question.

Comment: @AfsheenTaheri - No, it didn't. The path that you posted in your error doesn't come from your code. Either you're not showing the right error or you're not showing the right code. Can you explain that please?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying. I only ran this block of code from my script and the error occurred.

Comment: @AfsheenTaheri - The file `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Win213x_Lec_filename.docx` is in the **parent** folder of the folder you're getting the files for (`C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Win213Copy`). You can't a file in the parent folder with your code. So your error is wrong or your code is. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Enigmativity You were right it actually worked when I removed that path and just copied the files from the documents directory. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Copy-Item` expects `String` as input. So it calls the `ToString()` method of the `FileInfo` object `$i`. That returns only the file name, not full path. As source directory is not specified the current working directory is used. Solution is to use full path found in `fullname` property:

```
cp $i.fullname C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test\Lectures
```

From pipeline `Copy-Item` can handle `FileInfo` objects correctly, using the `fullname` property. Which you should remember not to drop if using `Select-Object`.

Comment: The `$i` instance is a `FileInfo` object. It contains the full path.

Comment: `Copy-Item` calls `ToString()` and there you get only file name. Try yourself if you don't believe.